# Can't display any number using 74HC595

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, programming

I just started using elegoo UNO R3 and I have the problem displaying different numbers on the segment display using the 74Hc595. I have no problem with the uploads and the circuits are working fine. However, the segment  doesn't display any numbers besides 8. Is there a problem with the code or the wiring? any suggestion?

```
byte seven_seg_digits[10] = { B11111100,  // = 0
                          B01100000,  // = 1
                          B11011010,  // = 2
                          B11110010,  // = 3
                          B01100110,  // = 4
                          B10110110,  // = 5
                          B10111110,  // = 6
                          B11100000,  // = 7
                          B11111110,  // = 8
                          B11100110   // = 9
                         };
// connect to the ST_CP of 74HC595 (pin 3,latch pin)
int latchPin = 3;
// connect to the SH_CP of 74HC595 (pin 4, clock pin)
int clockPin = 4;
// connect to the DS of 74HC595 (pin 2)
int dataPin = 2;



 void setup() {
  // Set latchPin, clockPin, dataPin as output
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
}

// display a number on the digital segment display
void sevenSegWrite(byte digit) {
  // set the latchPin to low potential, before sending data
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);

  // the original data (bit pattern)
  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, seven_seg_digits[digit]);  

  // set the latchPin to high potential, after sending data
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
}
   }

void loop() {       
  // count from 9 to 0
  for (byte digit = 10; digit > 0; --digit) {
    delay(0);
    sevenSegWrite(digit - 1); 
  }

  // suspend 4 seconds
  delay(0);
}
```

here is my circuit and the tutorial diagram:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I give you +1 for writing decent code.

Comment: Display get stuck at '8' or keep looping '9'-'8'? What if you count from 0 to 9?

Comment: display get stuck at 8

Comment: May be a silly comment, but you did change the argument in your two `delay(0);` calls to higher values, right? The display will seem to aggressively flicker while going through all digits, so it may just seem that it is "stuck" at lighting all LEDs.

Answer (score 3):

You're not giving your eyes time to see the numbers change. If you were [a pigeon](http://www.neatorama.com/2007/09/22/fun-pigeon-facts-super-vision/) you might just see some numbers flicker past very rapidly, but we mere humans don't have a hope of seeing them - not without introducing some delay.

```
void loop() {       
  // count from 9 to 0
  for (byte digit = 10; digit > 0; --digit) {
    delay(0);  // <--- Number of ms to wait between each digit
    sevenSegWrite(digit - 1); 
  }

  // suspend 4 seconds
  delay(0);  // <--- Number of ms to wait between counts.
}
```